# How to fill grid view with data from mysql database? (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

I'm trying to write a simple UWP app in C#. After clicking a button it should connect to MySQL remote database and post the result to grid view. As it has to be an UWP app, BindigSource and DataSource don't work. What changes should I made to work that app in UWP?

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    const string connString = "server=server_name; user id=uid; pwd=mypassword; persistsecurityinfo=True; database=mydb";

    string loadQuery = "SELECT * FROM table_name;";


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();

        MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(loadQuery, conn);

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        gridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
        mySqlDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);

        conn.Close();
    }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried any research? There is plenty of information to be found.

Comment: you are going about this in a weird way, you have everything looking good upto the lies after this, assuming this is a winforms application , you fill the datatable, after that just set the GidView.Datasource = your datata after that call the datagridview.DataBind() no need for update

Comment: @Crowcoder I have tried plenty of research, something like 6 hours today, there's plenty of info for Winforms but no UWP

Comment: A lot of information related to MVVM on WPF will be applicable. Did you see this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/xaml-basics-intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UWP `GridView` is very different from the one in Windows Forms. While Windows Forms `GridView` is basically a table similar to Excel, in UWP it is a list of items displayed in a grid. There is still a concept of rows and columns, but the items themselves don't care about the row or column they are in and items in a row or in a column are not logically related.

Your use case requires a tabular display, which is not available in the UWP SDK out of the box. Luckily however, you can find many great control on-line. Of the top of my mind you could look into the [Telerik UI for UWP](https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui), specifically its [Grid control](https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/grid). That should give you all you need to implement your scenario.